# Twilio Alphanumeric Sender id doesn't work from MS Access

Tags: ms-access, twilio

I am using [Devin Rader's VBA code to send SMS from MS Access](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17200913/648265), and it works fine.

But Alphanumeric Sender Id ([as specified in the FAQ/Doc](https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/sms/what-is-alphanumeric-sender-id-and-how-do-i-get-started), all one needs to do is to replace `FromNum` with the Id (<=11 chars)) only works for me when I do it from [Twilio API Explorer](https://www.twilio.com/user/account/developer-tools/api-explorer).

From MS Access, I end up with [error 21212](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/21212) ("Invalid 'From' Phone Number".

Answer (score 1):

Twilio evangelist here.

Sounds like you might be calling the older `/SMS` endpoint which does not support SenderID instead of the newer `/Messages` endpoint which does.  I've posted a set of updated code that uses the newer endpoint in GitHub:

https://github.com/devinrader/CallYourSpreadsheet/blob/master/Access/Exported/Twilio.bas

Hope that helps.