# Sending Twilio SMS with an Alphanumeric "From" returns the error message 'From' phone number is required

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, twilio

I am attempting to send SMS messages where I use a custom and human friendly "From" name.

I am able to send SMS fine - until I set the 'From' attribute to anything other than one of my valid Twilio numbers.

I have been testing this using a UK Twilio number sending to a UK mobile phone number, which Twilio list as a country capable of using alphanumeric from addresses.

Background : I am sending these SMS from Parse cloud code.

Here's my send code (Javascript).

```
function sendCodeSms(phoneNumber, code, prefix) {

// Define a human friendly 'from' address
var twilioFrom = 'Friendly';

// Use appropriate 'from' number - cover countries that don't allow alphanumerical from addresses
switch (prefix) {
    case "1":
        twilioFrom = twilioPhoneNumber_1;
        break;
}

// Create a promise
var promise = new Parse.Promise();

// Call the Twilio API
twilio.sendSms({
    to: prefix + phoneNumber.replace(/\D/g, ''),
    from: twilioFrom.replace(/\D/g, ''),
    body: 'Your login PIN is ' + code
}, function(err, responseData) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        promise.reject(err.message);
    } else {
        promise.resolve();
    }
});
return promise;
```

}

If I replace the `twilioFrom` value with one of my valid Twilit numbers then the SMS are sent fine.

Any ideas?  Help?

(Please don't let it be a school boy error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Apologies that the Twilio module is currently out of date on Parse. I am working with their team to get it up to date.

In the meantime, you don't need to write an entire module to use this functionality. Parse Cloud does supply a simple `httpRequest` module which you can use to send requests to the newer Twilio endpoints. Here is an example of a function to send an SMS message using the [Messages endpoint](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages):

```
var accountSid = 'AC123...'; // your account SID
var authToken  = 'xyzabc...'; // your auth token
var toNumber   = "+14515551234"; // the number you are sending a message to
var fromNumber = "HELLO"; // your alphanumeric string
var body       = "This is a message"; // your message to be sent

// Build up the URL
var url = 'https://';
url += accountSid + ':' + authToken + '@'; // add auth to URL
url += 'api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/';
url += accountSid;
url += '/Messages.json';

Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
  url: url,
  method: "POST",
  body: {
    "To": toNumber,
    "From": fromNumber,
    "Body": body
  }
}).then(function(httpResponse) {
  // success
  console.log(httpResponse.text);
  // httpResponse.data is the parsed JSON response
},function(httpResponse) {
  // error
  console.error('Request failed with response code ' + httpResponse.status);
});
```

Let me know if this helps at all.

Comment: this is excellent.  Of course I didn't think about the problem in a going back to basics way.  I'm SO glad you did.  Thank you.

Comment: No problem! Good luck with the rest of the app.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are removing all non numerical characters with .`replace`. So I think the `from` sent to twilio will be a blank string.

```
// Call the Twilio API
twilio.sendSms({
    to: prefix + phoneNumber.replace(/\D/g, ''),
    from: twilioFrom.replace(/\D/g, ''), // <--- Removing all non digit characters
    body: 'Your login PIN is ' + code
}, function(err, responseData) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        promise.reject(err.message);
    } else {
        promise.resolve();
    }
});
```

Comment: See. I thought school boy error.  However.  If I correct that then the error message changes to `'From' number Friendly is not a valid phone number or shortcode.`

Comment: Do you have an upgraded account? According to this link (https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/08/send-branded-sms-messages-using-twilio-alphanumeric-sender-id.html), to use alpha numeric  sender IDs you need to have upgraded your account.

Comment: Yes, it's an upgraded account - which actually just means that I'm paying for each number and SMS.  I've also checked the list of countries I can send SMS to - and that is fine also.

Comment: One last thing to check. It seems as if there is an older SMS end point that has been deprecated and doesn't support using alpha numeric sender IDs. It has been replaced by newer Messages end point. http://stackoverflow.com/a/34073490/3113384 It looks like the twilio cloud code module hasn't been updated in a while https://github.com/ParsePlatform/TwilioCloudModule/

Comment: Good spot!  reading the Parse documentation I find... "The built-in Twilio Cloud Module provides a subset of the functionality available to Twilio customers. If the feature you are interested in is not supported by this Cloud Module, you may want to consider writing your own Twilio JavaScript wrapper as a custom Cloud Module. We suggest looking at Twilio's node nodule for inspiration."

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

So the answer is (as found by dmullings) that the Twilio library provided by Parse only provides a **subset** of the Twilio capabilities.

> The built-in Twilio Cloud Module provides a subset of the
>   functionality available to Twilio customers. If the feature you are
>   interested in is not supported by this Cloud Module, you may want to
>   consider writing your own Twilio JavaScript wrapper as a custom Cloud
>   Module. We suggest looking at Twilio's node nodule for inspiration.

So the solution will be to create your own Twilio module.